# apt-get upgrade of google-cloud-sdk throwing errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have not found a way to report these bugs when updating Google Cloud SDK via apt-get on Ubuntu 18.04, so posting them here.

```
Setting up google-cloud-sdk (274.0.0-0) ...
Compiling platform/bq/third_party/yaml/lib3/__init__.py ...
File "platform/bq/third_party/yaml/lib3/__init__.py", line 284
class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

...

Processing triggers for google-cloud-sdk (274.0.0-0) ...
Compiling platform/bq/third_party/yaml/lib3/__init__.py ...
  File "platform/bq/third_party/yaml/lib3/__init__.py", line 284
    class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Setting up google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-go (274.0.0-0) ...
Processing triggers for google-cloud-sdk (274.0.0-0) ...
Compiling platform/bq/third_party/yaml/lib3/__init__.py ...
  File "platform/bq/third_party/yaml/lib3/__init__.py", line 284
    class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393454/google-cloud-sdk-installation-fails-on-python-syntax-error. BTW here is the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146447037

Answer (score 0):

Use Python 3 instead of Python 2.x versions